# ASP Net Core 2.2 Authorization redirect not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-authorization

I have an application that I want to authorize a controller action:

```
// GET: Manage
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Manage()
{
    var songs = _context.Songs
        .Include(s => s.Decades)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Title);

    return View(await songs.ToListAsync());
}
```

And I have setup my Startup.cs file as such:

```
using JukeboxJunkies.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace JukeboxJunkies
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityAppContext>();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                //options.LoginPath = "/Account/NotAuthorized";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/NotAuthorized";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            }).AddAuthentication();

            services.AddDbContext<IdentityAppContext>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("JukeboxJunkies"));
            });

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<JukeboxJunkiesEntities>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("JukeboxJunkies")));

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I hit the action on the controller, I expect to be routed to the NotAuthorized view - but it doesn't - it routes to the index view.

Ideas on what I could be missing?  Have I provided enough info?

Side note, if I uncomment out this line:

```
//options.LoginPath = "/Account/NotAuthorized";
```

It works just fine.

Comment: The default for `options.LoginPath` with this setup is `/Account/Login`, so I'm surprised it routes to the index view and not that. Other than that, what you've described is the correct behaviour. Adding `[Authorize]` means the app needs to first figure out who you are - if it can't do that, it wants you to log in. You'll only see access denied if you're identified but don't have permission.

Comment: I just confirmed - thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem. Does that mean you've resolved this now?

Comment: Yes. I think all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default scaffolded Identity pages this is the case.
By default, Asp.Net Core Access denied path is `k.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied"` and login path: `k.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";`
so by placing another view to display, the rendering engine searches for the the view which you want displayed but doesn't find it so it just redirects to the index page since you have overridden the default values. That's why when you uncomment the line, it works properly. When you comment it, your have overridden the default values